# How to get only date from datetime in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have data in MySQL table like :

```
ID     dates                   value
1    2011-12-18 10:11:12      test1
2    2011-12-18 12:11:12      test2
3    2011-11-18 10:19:11      test3
```

When I tried to get value in module it not work, I write code like :

```
$query=$this->db->get_where('datas', array('dates' => date('Y-m-d')));
```

I need to get data from whole day like get data only from 2011-12-18.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `$this->db->like();`

so it will be

```
$query=$this->db->like('dates', array('dates' => date('Y-m-d')));
```

the `%` will be added automatically

also you have datas as key, and should be dates based on database structure

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```html
$date="2018-09-19";
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_name');
$this->db->where('DATE(date_time_col)', $date);
$query = $this->db->get();
$res= $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

In your table, create an *int field* with the name *ts*.

When you insert data into this table, use the **time()** method to insert a timestamp into **ts**.

```
$data = array(
   'dates' => '<your date value>' ,
   'value' => '<your value>' ,
   'ts'    => time()
);

$this->db->insert('datas', $data);
```

**Then, when querying:**

Use the mktime() method to create a timestamp range for the start & end of today.

```
$start = mktime() - date('h')*3600;    
$end   = mktime(); 

$this->db->where('ts >=', $start);
$this->db->where('ts <=', $end);
```

Make sure you've indexed the ts column. This will also be faster than the above *LIKE* method on larger datasets.